# How to correctly use Javascript onclick Function?

Tags: javascript

So I have a Button on my main.html page which when clicked I would like it to invoke a determineWinner function from my main.js file to determine the winner of a simple board game depending on points scored.however when run the button has no effect!

essentially what I have tried to do looks as follows:

```
<div id="userControls">
  <button class="button End Game" onclick="decideWinner();">End Game</button>
</div>
```

the corresponding function to be invoked then looks like:

```
function decideWinner(){

  if (document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML > document.getElementById('enemyScoreDiv').innerHTML
  && document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML >= 10
){
    alert("You Win!");
  }


  else if (document.getElementById('enemyScoreDiv').innerHTML > document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML
  && document.getElementById('enemyScoreDiv').innerHTML >= 10
){
    alert("You Lose!");
  }

  else if (document.getElementById('enemyScoreDiv').innerHTML === document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML
  && document.getElementById('enemyScoreDiv').innerHTML >= 10 && document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML >= 10
){
    alert("Draw!");
  }
}
```

I have tried a number of 'fixes' found online to try and remedy this such as capitalising onClick, adding semicolon to the function call etc
but still the button has no effect.

full code: https://codepen.io/Qwerty1571/pen/QPYqoY 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a more complete example, including HTML that contains the elements you are using for the scores (`userScoreDiv`, etc). As a side note, you should be storing scores in variables instead of relying on the value of DOM elements.

Comment: Code should be in the question itself because external links aren't always accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked into your code and `decideWinner` does get called, the problem is here:

`if(document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML > document.getElementById('enemyScoreDiv').innerHTML)`

`document.getElementById('userScoreDiv').innerHTML` is a string, in your case it can be `"User Score: 0"`. Lets say the score is 10:9 for the player. In that case you would compare if `"User Score: 10" > "Robot Score: 9"`. This can obviously not work. Instead use this as your `decideWinner` function:

```
function decideWinner() {
    //score and roboScore are global variables in his/her code
    if (score > roboScore && score >= 10) {
        alert("You Win!");
    } else if (roboScore > score && score >= 10) {
        alert("You Lose!");
    } else if (roboScore === score && roboScore >= 10 && score >= 10) {
        alert("Draw!");
    } else {
      //If playerScore < 10 and robotScore < 10 then this gets called
      console.log("No winner yet!")
    }
}
```

[Codepen with working code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYjZJp?editors=1111)

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

> You call `determineWinner` but you function is called `decideWinner`.
>
> This should work:
>
> ```
> <div id="userControls">
>    <button class="button End Game" onclick="decideWinner()">End Game</button>
> </div>
> ```
>
> ```js
>  
>  function decideWinner() {
>    console.log("The winner is me")
>  }
> ```
>
> ```html
>  
>  <div id="userControls">
>    <button class="button End Game" onclick="decideWinner()">End Game</button>
>  </div>
> ```
>
> If it still does not work for you then you probably haven't loaded the
>   script correctly or your script can't be compiled.

Comment: @esqew apologies I made a mistake when copying code to this post, but  the function has been correctly referenced - both being decideWinner() so I i'm unsure of what the problem is.. Am I able to call an alert from the onclick function?

Comment: @Qwerty7152 Yes you can call `alert` from `onclick` like this `onclick="alert()"`. Please provide all of your js and html so I can look into it further

Comment: @Qwerty7152 Please fix the code in your question so it won't confuse people. Also, provide a more complete example so we can help find the problem.

Comment: @Wendelin I've Updated the question with a link to a working example of the complete code

Comment: @Qwerty7152 I've updated my answer, please check it out

Comment: @Wendelin Thanks so much for the effort you put into your answer, I have changed my code to reflect you're updated answer (which makes much more sense) however the function is still not called when the 'end game' button is clicked

Comment: @Qwerty7152 Strange :/ I have added a link to a codepen with my code. For me the function gets called and I always get an alert or a console log entry ("No winner yet!"). Let me know if you can spot any differences to your code.

Comment: @Wendelin I have compared you're code to mine, and I am able to replicate your results in codepen, however when I run my code in a browser via a localhost it doesnt work, I tried it in 4 different  browsers to test if it was a browser specific problem but apparently not, I cant think of any reasoning for this unless they don't like alerts, suppose I could try create a new div to display the results of the decideWinner function there?

Comment: @Wendelin It was an issue with the localhost I was using, Problemo solved! Thank you!

Comment: @Qwerty7152 Great but you should still mark this as the correct answer since it does answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want an event listener for an element here is what you do.

```
<button id="btn1">Click to Fire Below Event</button>

var el = document.getElementById( 'btn1' );

el.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //Your Code Goes Here
});
```

Answer (score -2):

The name of the function you wanna call is different from that one you're calling.